# Solve a maze using multicores?

Tags: multithreading, multicore

This question is messy, i dont need a working solution, i need some psuedo code.

How would i solve this maze? This is a homework question. I have to get from point green to red. At every fork i need to 'spawn a thread' and go that direction. I need to figure out how to get to red but i am unsure how to avoid paths i already have taken (finishing with any path is ok, i am just not allowed to go in circles).

Heres an example of my problem, i start by moving down and i see a fork so one goes right and one goes down (or this thread can take it, it doesnt matter). Now lets ignore the rest of the forks and say the one going right hits the wall, goes down, hits the wall and goes left, then goes up. The other thread goes down, hits the wall then goes all the way right. The bottom path has been taken twice, by starting at different sides.

How do i mark this path has been taken? Do i need a lock? Is this the only way? Is there a lockless solution?

Implementation wise i was thinking i could have the maze something like this. I dont like the solution because there is a LOT of locking (assuming i lock before each read and write of the haveTraverse member). I dont need to use the MazeSegment class below, i just wrote it up as an example. I am allowed to construct the maze however i want. I was thinking maybe the solution requires no connecting paths and thats hassling me. Maybe i could split the map up instead of using the format below (which is easy to read and understand). But if i knew how to split it up i would know how to walk it thus the problem.

How do i walk this maze efficiently?

The only hint i receive was dont try to conserve memory by reusing it, make copies. However that was related to a problem with ordering a list and i dont think the hint was a hint for this.

```
class MazeSegment
{
    enum Direction { up, down, left, right}
    List<Pair<Direction, MazeSegment*>> ConnectingPaths;
    int line_length;
    bool haveTraverse;
}

MazeSegment root;

class MazeSegment
{
    enum Direction { up, down, left, right}
    List<Pair<Direction, MazeSegment*>> ConnectingPaths;
    bool haveTraverse;
}

void WalkPath(MazeSegment segment)
{
    if(segment.haveTraverse) return;
    segment.haveTraverse = true;
    foreach(var v in segment)
    {
        if(v.haveTraverse == false)
            spawn_thread(v);
    }
}

WalkPath(root);
```

[image]

Comment: Have you asked your teacher / professor if it is OK to solicit help like this?

Comment: Might this be one of the problems that gets a superlinear speedup from parallelism?

Comment: Thanks to everyone who answered. I really like them! (and at @emery, yes, he said you can ask friends but try to figure it out before asking. I only thought locks werent the optimal solution)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using the usual "read, calculate new value, compare-and-swap, repeat until CAS succeeds" method commonly found in lock-free programming.

All grid-squares in your maze start should hold a pointer representing the direction to move to reach the exit.  Initially they all are "unknown".

Walk the maze starting at the exit.  On each square reached, use compare and swap to replace "unknown" with the direction to the square this thread previously processed.  If CAS fails, you've got a loop, prune that branch.  If CAS succeeds, continue forward.  When you assign a direction to the entrance, you now can follow the path to the exit.

Answer (score 4):

**Parallel Breadth-First Search**

Search for parallel or multithread bread first traversal, which is basically what you're doing.  Each time you come to a fork in your maze (where you can take one of several paths), you create a new worker thread to continue the search down each of the possible paths and report back which one gets you to the end.

It's similar to "simple" breadth first searches, except the subtrees can be searched in parallel.

If this were a pure tree data structure, you wouldn't need to lock, but since it's a graph traversal you will need to keep track of your visited nodes.  So, the code which sets the "visited" flag of each node will need to be protected with a lock.

Here's a good example program.  It uses audio feedback, so be sure your speakers are on.

> http://www.break.com/games/maze15.html

Comment: From the question description, he's figured that part out.  But he's stuck on loop detection.

Comment: Wrong link?  Seems unrelated to automatic maze solving.

Comment: crap, lol. i couldnt resist passing '4 levels'. Now i realize it was a great setup to the joke. I jumped, you got me. +1 for the joke.

Comment: @Ben, you need to pass through the first levels to see.

Answer (score 3):

Off hand, given your structure above, I could see solving this by adding an 'int Seen' to each MazeSegement instead of 'bool haveTraverse'.  You could then use a interlocked increment on the 'Seen' variable as you're looping over the ConnectedPaths and only spawn a thread to take the path if the 'Seen' increment returns 1 (assuming Seen is initialized to 0).

So the code becomes something like

```
void WalkPath(MazeSegment segment)
{
    foreach(var v in segment.ConnectedPaths)
    {
        if( Interlocked.Increment( &v.Path.Seen ) == 1)
            spawn_thread(v.Path);
    }
}
```

Other threads which might attempt to take the same path should get something >1.  Because interlocked.increment would guarantee a thread-safe increment then we don't have to worry about 2 threads getting a result of '1' so only one thread should take a given path.

Comment: Nice, is it really that simple? I googled Interlocked.Increment and see its atomic. Do you know if this is a single instruction on the CPU (aka fast)? Its not like a complex locking function?

Comment: Actually you want Interlocked Exchange, not Interlocked Increment.  But this is definitely a feasible solution.

Comment: The hard part of this solution will be that C++ has no builtin interlocked libraries, so depending on the platform being used the headers/code used will be different.  If this is homework, all the code might have to be relatively cross platform.

Comment: @Ben Voigt ahh yes, didn't know about interlocked exchange, i'm more familiar with interlocked increment.  @acidzombie24 With interlocked exchange you could still have 'hasTraversed'.  You would just interlocked exchange it with 'true' and if the return value is 'false' you know you're the first and only thread to visit the path.

Comment: @Chris I saw somewhere that thread-safe functions are looking to be added in C++0x so this might not be so bad in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Create a class (Worker) instances of which hold a path taken so far, and can only `advance()` through a straight corridor at given direction. At every intersection, drop the worker object which holds the path before intersection, and create two (or three) new objects, with a copy of that path and different turns taken.

Put these worker objects into a queue. Notice how every one of them is independent from another, so you may take several of them from the queue and `advance()` in parallel. You can simply create as many threads, or use a pool of threads according to the number of cores you have. Once any of the workers advance to the destination square, output the paths it holds, it is a solution.

Consider traversing the maze from exit to entry. In a real maze, blind alleys are intended to slow down motion form entry to exit, but rarely the other way around.

Consider adding a loop detection mechanism, e.g. by comparing intersections that make up your path with an intersection you encounter.

Consider using a hand-made linked list to represent the path. Note how inserting a new head to a linked list does not change the rest of it, so you can share the tail with other instances that don't modify it. This will reduce memory footprint and time needed to spawn a worker (only noticeable at rather large mazes).